# Objective-C Syntax issue

Tags: objective-c

I'm not very familiar with Obj-C and am trying to do something very simple but can't figure out the syntax around expressions, braces, etc.

I have:

```
type foo = {
  thing(text),
  .paramA = 4.0f,
  .paramB = 20.0f,
};
```

I'm trying to simply wrap that in a ternary and make it nil in some cases, but no matter what I try (wrapping it in parens, braces, etc), x-code complains at me for various reasons:

```
type foo = condition
  ? {
    thing(text),
    .paramA = 4.0f,
    .paramB = 20.0f,
  }
  : nil;
```

help?  :)

Comment: Except for the term `nil` I don't see anything that looks remotely like Objective-C in your code. I don't actually know what language it is (I don't know a language with keyword `type`) but it might be C.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is difficult in objectiveC (but almost trivial and exactly like you've typed it in swift) for a couple of reasons

1. We can't create tuples ( String , Float, Float ) on the fly. We can declare a struct, but sadly due to ARC we can't really have a string member in a struct (any longer *sigh)
2. In objectiveC only pointer types can be set to nil, a struct or primitive (value type) can't, so you'd need to be dealing with a pointer to that struct or primitive.

For these reasons the easiest approach, despite that it might seem ridiculous overkill, is to make type a class (with properties for the three variables you need) and therefore foo will be a pointer of type Type*

Best.

Answer (score -1):

Your first code example is not Objective-C; it's C (maybe).

Your second code example tries to introduce `nil`, but there is no `nil` in C. You can *never* assign `nil` where a C type is expected. `nil` can only be assigned where an Objective-C object is expected, and you don't have an Objective-C object. You might stretch a point and assign it where a C pointer is expected (since that is how an object is expressed), but you don't have a C pointer either.

Comment: nil is usually simply defined as (void*)0, so in fact assignable to any C pointer. Just a convention to denote a NULL value for objects.

Comment: @Macmade OK, fine. He hasn't got an object, and he hasn't got a C pointer either.